How to I can get threads-user-id to publish a post on threads using Threads Graph API
In threads documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/threads/posts
They gives the details of Threads Graph API to post content on Threads platform. Here: 
They don't mention that how  we can get our threads-user-id.
Please tell me how I can get that.
I already search on Facebook developer account and they don't mention any type of thread-user-id their.
I used my threads account username but it didn't work for me as well.

Make a request to the /me endpoint using the user access token, that will get you the ID - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/threads/threads-profiles You can actually use me in most places, instead of a user ID - it will resolve to the ID of the user whose access token you are using.

@C3roe yes this works, thanks for it
